# GSM Modem Minicom Press OK

Tags: command, gsm, at-command, modem

I am using a minicom to send load from one phone to another. I use the AT+STKTR commands to move on from one task to the next. However, I got stuck when I got a response of "D6!, +Load 09********* to 09********* (Press OK)". What is the command for pressing OK? What is the best solution for this. Thanks for the help. Any help will be appreciated!